# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la multiplicación de todas las posibles combinaciones de 2 columnas en un dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe de más de 1000 filas

```
  obs    AGRO COMER CONST ELECT MANUF MINER PESCA SERV PBI
1 1994Q1   1   1     1     1     1     1     1     1   1
2 1994Q2   1   1     1     1     1     1     1     1   1
3 1994Q3   1   1     1     1     1     0     1     1   1
4 1994Q4   1   1     1     0     1     0     0     0   0
5 1995Q1   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0   0
6 1995Q2   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0   0
```

Me gustaría en un nuevo dataframe poder obtener la multiplicación de todas las posibles combinaciones de 2 en 2. Por ejemplo:

```
AGROxCOMER, COMERxCONST, CONSTxELECT, ..., SERVxPBI, AGROxCONST, COMERxELECT, ..., AGROxELECT, COMERxMANUF, ..., MINxPBI, AGROxMANUF, COMERxMIN, MANUFxPBI, ......., AGROxPBI.
```

El total de columnas de este nuevo dataframe debe 36. Alguien tiene alguna solución?
Yo tuve que crear muchos Bucles para poder resolverlo

Comment: This site is Spanish-only. Please, rewrite in Spanish or try your luck in stackoverflow.com

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Hi. spanish is the official language for this site. please translate the question, if not it could be close.

Comment: Hasta donde entiendo, solo serían necesarios dos bucles para recorrer todas las posibles combinaciones. Tal vez mostrando como lo hiciste, podríamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma bastante sencilla sería generar previamente la lista con las combinaciones posibles y sobre ella trabajar:

```
df <- read.table(text="obs    AGRO COMER CONST ELECT MANUF MINER PESCA SERV PBI
1994Q1   1   1     1     1     1     1     1     1   1
1994Q2   1   1     1     1     1     1     1     1   1
1994Q3   1   1     1     1     1     0     1     1   1
1994Q4   1   1     1     0     1     0     0     0   0
1995Q1   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0   0
1995Q2   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0   0", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Variables a combinar
variables <- names(df)[-1]
# Combinaciones de las variables
combinaciones <- combn(variables, 2)
combinaciones

     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]   [,8]   [,9]    [,10]  
[1,] "AGRO"  "AGRO"  "AGRO"  "AGRO"  "AGRO"  "AGRO"  "AGRO" "AGRO" "COMER" "COMER"
[2,] "COMER" "CONST" "ELECT" "MANUF" "MINER" "PESCA" "SERV" "PBI"  "CONST" "ELECT"
     [,11]   [,12]   [,13]   [,14]   [,15]   [,16]   [,17]   [,18]   [,19]   [,20]  
[1,] "COMER" "COMER" "COMER" "COMER" "COMER" "CONST" "CONST" "CONST" "CONST" "CONST"
[2,] "MANUF" "MINER" "PESCA" "SERV"  "PBI"   "ELECT" "MANUF" "MINER" "PESCA" "SERV" 
     [,21]   [,22]   [,23]   [,24]   [,25]   [,26]   [,27]   [,28]   [,29]   [,30]  
[1,] "CONST" "ELECT" "ELECT" "ELECT" "ELECT" "ELECT" "MANUF" "MANUF" "MANUF" "MANUF"
[2,] "PBI"   "MANUF" "MINER" "PESCA" "SERV"  "PBI"   "MINER" "PESCA" "SERV"  "PBI"  
     [,31]   [,32]   [,33]   [,34]   [,35]   [,36] 
[1,] "MINER" "MINER" "MINER" "PESCA" "PESCA" "SERV"
[2,] "PESCA" "SERV"  "PBI"   "SERV"  "PBI"   "PBI"
```

Con `combn()` generamos todas las combinaciones de dos elementos de las variables en cuestión, y ahora sí, con cada combinación, aplicamos una función que multiplica las columnas a la que hace referencia cada combinación.

```
prod <- apply(combinaciones, MARGIN = 2, FUN=function(x) df[,x[1]]*df[,x[2]])
```

Por último, configuramos los nombres de las columnas de una forma similar

```
nombres <- apply(combinaciones, MARGIN = 2, FUN=function(x) paste0(x[1], 'x', x[2]))
colnames(prod) <- nombres

prod[,1:10]

    AGROxCOMER AGROxCONST AGROxELECT AGROxMANUF AGROxMINER AGROxPESCA AGROxSERV AGROxPBI COMERxCONST COMERxELECT
[1,]          1          1          1          1          1          1         1        1           1           1
[2,]          1          1          1          1          1          1         1        1           1           1
[3,]          1          1          1          1          0          1         1        1           1           1
[4,]          1          1          0          1          0          0         0        0           1           0
[5,]          0          0          0          0          0          0         0        0           0           0
[6,]          0          0          0          0          0          0         0        0           0           0
```